# JQuery .on() to prevent submission of a dynamically created form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

All of the forms in my web application require validation before they are submitted. This code is doing the job properly:

```
    $(document).on("submit",'form',function(){
    // loop through $(this) and check each .required field and increment a counter
        // if counter > 0 then return false
    });
```

However the validation is not triggered when I submit a form that was added to the DOM after the page loaded.

I am not getting any errors in my console log (with 'Preserve log upon navigation' on).

To date, the .on() event has worked correctly on dynamically created elements but this one has me stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: can u provide us jsfiddle ?

Comment: What you've got should work fine on *all* forms, and if it isn't you're going to have to post more code or try to replicate the issue somewhere we can see it.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used jsfiddle before. It's on my list of things to learn. In any case, I'm not sure how I would go about demonstrating a dynamically created form without having to upload a substantial part of the application and it's classes.

Comment: I am uploading the whole thing to a server now for testing. Will post another comment with the URL when it's online. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - it's online at http://www.nadeemh.com/preview/balloon/

Login with 'nadeem@nadeemh.com' and '123456'

Click on 'Nadeem' on the top right, then on a any link under 'Completed Projects'. This will open a 'Manage Completed Projects' box. The form on the right should not submit but it does. And it's killing me.

Comment: I've found the problem - I'm so embarrassed. This is what happens when you haven't slept more than 8 hours in three days ;-) The form loads with values in all the fields which are supposed to be replaced by the proper form values but aren't. Which means that all the fields contain a value and pass the validation. So sorry to have wasted your time. Thanks.